# The js files from skin directory not loading in Magento

Tags: magento, skin

I am trying to use the magento for ecommerce.

In that i just added some js file which are held on the skin\frontend\default\mytheme\js.

This is my code:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jscommon/jquery.min.js</script></action>
<block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles_default.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/dd.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
<!-- <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name></action> -->
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jqueryNoConf.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.anythingslider.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.dd.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/anythingslider.css</name></action>
<!--<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/scripts.js</name></action>-->
</block>
```

But from this line `<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.min.js</name></action>` nothing will be loaded in browser. Nothing means even the script loading url not coming...

The code wrote in the `page.xml` from `C:\wamp\www\theme\app\design\frontend\default\biomatrix\template\layout`

What is teh problem in my code.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you have kept js files in **skin\frontend\default\mytheme\js** path.

and you are writing code in page.xml placed in C:\wamp\www\theme\app\design\frontend**default\biomatrix**\template\layout folder

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a path in the root js folder and create a folder like prototype , lib or mage
and call it with

```
 <action method="addJs"><script>your folder/yourjs.js</script></action>
```